# JavaFX ScrollPane: disable panning for touch events

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, pan, panning, scrollpane

I have a problem with a ScrollPane. I want to disable the panning. For the mouse it's very easy because of the setPannable(boolean) function. But that doesn't disable the panning for touch events. So is there a way to disable panning for touch events in a ScrollPane?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I now have a working solution. In the control you do not want to have scrolling of the scrollpane during DRAG operations add following filter.

```
// Filter all SCROLL Events, otherwise the parent scroll pane will pan, 
// somehow is this workaround 

button2.addEventFilter(InputEvent.ANY, (event)-> {
    if (event.getEventType().toString() == "SCROLL")
        event.consume();
});
```

button2 is a simple ToggleButton. Should work with any other control.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement the setOnTouch...() methods associated with touch events for your ScrollPane ?
If you consume the event then touch gestures will have no effects.

Example :

```
    ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
    sp.addEventHandler(TouchEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<TouchEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TouchEvent event) {
            event.consume();                
        }
    });
```

Hope I helped you

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't work. Anyway thanks for your attempt.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help, my answer wasn't very clear so I added a little example. Did you tried this ?